# actionscript 3, removeEventListener not working properly

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, event-listener

I've made this game with event listener (*coordinates*) on mouse position when a click occurs (to move the character).

I've another event listener for drag and drop (to combine items) that works pretty well.

```
function stageDown (event:MouseEvent):void
        {               
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, coordinates);
            MovieClip(getChildByName(event.target.name).toString()).startDrag();
            MovieClip(getChildByName(event.target.name).toString()).addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stageUp);

            ...stuff..

        }

function stageUp(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        stopDrag();

        ...stuff...

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, coordinates);
    }
```

In the function stageDown I remove the event listener for the movement(*coordinates*), than I add it again at the end of the function stageUp (when you release the mouse button and the drag is complete)

But is not working, when I release the drag the character start moving, can't understand why

Comment: is your `stageDown` handler attached to the stage (as the name may suggest)? or the item(s) your are dragging?

Comment: `MovieClip(getChildByName(event.target.name).toString()).startDrag();` oh dear!

Comment: oh dear indeed, guess the simple "event.target.startDrag()" is not trendy enough ....

Comment: @Stevemaster - did you get it figured out?

Comment: @BotMaster xD omg what a shame, im totally noob on as3. corrected thanks!

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis stageDown handler is dynamically attached to movieclip item you are clicking. "stageDown" is indeed not a good name, sorry, it belongs to an older version of the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the why (something to do with how Click events are tracked I suppose) but it is the 'normal' behavior.

Here is how I've handled this in the past.  Basically you can add a higher priority click listener to the object you are dragging and cancel the event there:  (see code comments)

```
//Assuming you have something like this in your code/////////
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, coordinates);

function coordinates(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("STAGE CLICK");  //whatever you do here
} ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//add your mouse down listener to your object
someObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stageDown);

//ALSO add a click listener to your object, and add it with higher priority than your stage mouse click listener
someObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClick, false, 999);

function itemClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    //stop the event from reaching the lower priority stage mouse click handler
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    trace("Item CLICK");
}

function stageDown (event:MouseEvent):void
{               
    Sprite(event.currentTarget).startDrag();
    //listen for the mouse up on the stage as sometimes when dragging very fast there is slight delay and the object may not be under the mouse
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stageUp, true);

    //if you don't care about mouse up on stage, then you can just forget the mouse up listener and handler altogether and just stop drag on the itemClick function.
}

function stageUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //remove the stage mouse up listener
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stageUp, true);
    trace("UP");
    stopDrag();
}
```